# Why does the Facebook JavaScript SDK request all these files?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to optimise the use of the Facebook SDK. Looking at Chrome's network tab shows me that when the SDK loads, it pulls in numerous other files:

[image]

The first one is *all.js*, which contains the Facebook API. The rest of the resources in the screenshot are loaded after the call to `FB.init`.

There are 3 calls to *about:blank*, and 3 calls to *xd_arbiter.php*. There are 2 calls to *oauth*. I can't work out why there are 3 calls to the first two.

It appears that *all.js* creates 2 `iframe` elements (if the page that loads the SDK is served over HTTPS, only one is created - the `fb_xdm_frame_https` one. In this situation, it seems that 2 requests are made instead of 3):

```html
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px; ">
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <iframe id="fb_xdm_frame_http" name="fb_xdm_frame_http"></iframe>
            <iframe id="fb_xdm_frame_https" name="fb_xdm_frame_https"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Blank pages are requested because the `iframe` elements are created with no `src` attribute (it's added later via JavaScript). When it gets set, it gets set to *xd_arbiter.php*.

So that explains 2 of the 3. But where do the other calls to *about:blank* and *xd_arbiter.php* come from? I've got this far by running *all.js* through [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and following the code, but I can't see why or how those files are requested a third time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xd_arbiter.php` is part of the infrastructure used to facilitate cross-domain messaging between your page and all subsequent widgets or dialogs displayed, or the main Facebook site if used as a Canvas page.

That you are seeing two requests for /dialog/oauth seems to be an issue with your implementation, are you manually calling `FB.getLoginstatus(.., true)` in addition to setting `status: true`?

Anyway, the third request for `xd_arbiter.php` is simply the response to the /dialog/oauth request being returned through the cross-domain channel, and since the `xd_arbiter.php` resources are cached (you seem to have caching disabled, as evident by the last request for xd_arbiter) no real cost is really incurred.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can tell there was no call to `getLoginStatus`, but the `status` option was set to `true`. Setting it to `false` seems to reduce the number of requests to what I would expect.

Comment: Then you most definitely are doing both the implicit auth ping (status:true) as well as doing an explicit one - now you're left with only the explicit one.

Comment: @SeanKinsey But why the 2 Iframes ( http , https) are on My page ?  AFAIK the whole idea is that FB.login opens the pop up and then creates **another** IFRAME inside of it with a `SRC` of my page url , and then he can send the information to the parent window via `window.top.sendUserObj({...})`. or am i getting this whole wrong?   [I thought it is something like this](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_J_O5p0PcuKo/SkWdB-b4ZsI/AAAAAAAAHiQ/UDa_U9xUFAo/s800/cross-domain-iframe-height-lg.jpg)....(p.s. Im using chrome 27 and still see those iframes.) Can you please explain ?

Comment: @SeanKinsey I asked it here. I'll be glad the get an answer :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862207/facebook-and-cross-domain-messaging-clarification